# Rust cannot automatically infer type of the parameter

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a trait that will allow Option<T> and T to be passed to a function.
But the function call does not compile without type annotation for this trait. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b4cb58ab58c9edfff55481150a40d87))

```rust
pub trait IntoOption<T> {
    fn into_option(self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T> IntoOption<T> for T {
    fn into_option(self) -> Option<T> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
impl<T> IntoOption<T> for Option<T> {
    fn into_option(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

fn test_fn<O, T>(value: O) -> Option<i32>
where
    O: IntoOption<T>,
    T: Into<i32>,
{
    match value.into_option() {
        None => None,
        Some(i) => Some(i.into())
    }
}


fn main() {
    test_fn(1); // Ok
    test_fn::<Option<i32>, i32>(Some(1)); // Ok
    test_fn(Some(1)); // Error "Cannot infer type"
}
```

How can I make the compiler automatically detect the type?

Comment: How is Rust supposed to decide between the two implementations of IntoOption?

Comment: You can use [`Into<Option<u32>>`](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/139ysg0/thoughts_on_the_ergonomics_of_impl_intooptiont/) instead, but it still has gotchas both at the caller and the callee side, so not exactly recommended to do so.

Comment: The issue is that `Option<T>` can have `T` also be an `Option<U>`, and then `U` can be `Option<V>`, ...  you cannot say “this type cannot be an `Option`”

Answer (score 0):

You have constrained `T` such that it must implement `Into<i32>` but `u32` does not (it implements [`TryInto<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-TryFrom%3Cu32%3E-for-i32) as the op is fallible).

```rust
fn test_fn<O, T>(value: O) -> Option<i32>
where
    O: IntoOption<T>,
    T: Into<i32>,
{
```

**edit**: you edited the question and changed the code after this answer was posted.

For future readers, the code initially had:

```rust
test_fn(Some(1 as u32)); // Error "Cannot infer type"
```

You also have blanket implementations which overlap and that is not allowed. When `T` is `Option<_>`, it will have two implementations applied to it:

```rust
impl<T> IntoOption<T> for T {
    fn into_option(self) -> Option<T> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
impl<T> IntoOption<T> for Option<T> {
    fn into_option(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
```

Comment: u32 it's my mistake.
And how do I split the implementations so it works for any types?

Comment: You don't. It isn't possible in Rust today (v1.75.0).

Odds are, you don't need that trait. I'd dump it.